# How do I delete the DMP files from Symantec Endpoint Protection's Data Install directory?

Tags: windows-server-2003, symantec-endpoint-protection

I have Symantec Endpoint Protection on our server at the directory is full of 1GB DMP files going back 6 months, which has filled the server's disk.

I can't seem to be able to delete these files:

[image]

I've tried the following things without success

- Stop all the Symantec services in Services ([as far as possible])[2](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/not-able-disable-sep121-services-servicesmsc#comment-6347201)
- Reboot
- Use Unlocker to try and remove the files, even at next reboot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly a second reboot did allow the files to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I am Chetan Savade from Symantec Technical Support Team.

Could you try the following workaround.

WORKAROUND

For a single client:

1. Disable Tamper Protection.
2. Open a Command Prompt window.
3. `del "C:\ProgramData\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.1.5337.5000.105\Data\Install\Logs\*.dmp"`
4. Using regedit.exe, set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE(\Wow6432Node\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\CurrentVersion\Common Client\Debug\CrashHandler\DumpOn*` to 0.
5. Re-enable Tamper Protection.
6. Open a Command Prompt window.
7. cd "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.1.5337.5000.105\Bin`"
8. `smc -stop`
9. `smc -start`

Comment: How do you disable tamper protection?

Comment: @MatthewLock Here's a guide on disabling Tamper Protection. https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH192023.html

Answer (score -1):

Login the PC with Safemode; 
Change the settings to show the hidden files;
Browse the folder
Delete it